# Replicate Form Action with PHP cURL

Tags: php, html, forms, curl

I'm currently building a webapp that's built on top of the ODK Aggregate server and Collect application. The front end collects data from users and converts it into an XML file that's compliant with the server where it is the uploaded to.

I've developed it in stages, as I'm uploading to the server automatically from it's /formUpload location, which is an external location. When using a form that takes in file input, I have the full url of the /formUpload location in the form action. When I do this, it all gets submitted perfectly fine.

However, as the form data will be generated into xml dynamically and not taken from a file input, I needed to find another way to submit this xml file to the server. I've been trying to get it to work using cURL all day but with no success. The error message that's returned is as follows:

Error: Did not receive Form Name or Form XML description.

I've concluded that this is occuring due to a difference in what is being submitted. Whilst I'm definitely submitting the same file as a multipart/form-data, I feel like the format of my PHP submission must differ slightly from the format of an HTML form.

Does anyone know what the HTML form should look like in a cURL request to make this work? Here are the two sets of data:

Form:

```
<form id="ie_backward_compatible_form" action='upload.php'
      enctype="multipart/form-data" encoding="multipart/form-data"
      method="POST" accept-charset="UTF-8">

    <table id="uploadTable">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="form_def_file">Form definition (xml file):</label>
            </td>

            <td>
                <input id="form_def_file" class="gwt-Button" type="file"
                       name="form_def_file" size="80">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <label for="mediaFiles">Optional Media file(s):</label>
            </td>

            <td>
                <input id="mediaFiles" class="gwt-Button" type="file"
                       multiple="" name="datafile" size="80,20">
                <input id="clear_media_files" class="gwt-Button"
                       type="button"
                       onclick="clearMediaInputField('mediaFiles')"
                       value="Clear">
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <input class="gwt-Button" type="button"
                       value="Upload Form" name="button" onclick="submitXML()">
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php

if (!empty ($_POST['xmlDoc']))
{
    $milliseconds = round(microtime(true) * 1000);
    $doc = $_POST["xmlDoc"];
    $dest = "uploads/tmp/tmp_".$milliseconds.".xml";

    file_put_contents($dest , $doc );

    // initialise the curl request
    $request = curl_init('https://odk-aggregate-test-158709.appspot.com/formUpload');
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt(
        $request,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
        array(
            'form_def_file' =>
                '@'.$dest ,
            'datafile' => ''
        ));

    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($request, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    echo curl_exec($request);

    if(curl_error($request))
    {
        echo 'error:' . curl_error($request);
    }
    // close the session
    curl_close($request);
}

?>
```

Also note, if any of that PHP looks terrible, it's because it probably is. I have never used it before and everything that's done there is from grabbing sources everywhere I could to do what I needed to with this form.

All help is much appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with your curl request.  This error looks like it might be stemming from an issue with the XML.  I think [this](https://github.com/opendatakit/aggregate/blob/master/src/main/java/org/opendatakit/aggregate/constants/ErrorConsts.java#L53) is the error you're getting from a 3rd party Java library.  The curl POST is proper.  Does `$_POST["xmlDoc"]` in your code actually contain anything, or is it an empty string?  That error message might stem from empty or invalid XML.

Comment: I don't think that's the case, as I'm able to echo out that variable and see the correct information. When I press submit, a JS function is called that generates that xml file and passes it to the php via an AJAX call.

Comment: Maybe, but follow the `MISSING_FORM_INFO` error constant from that Java library and that might provide a clue.  Otherwise, are you using PHP 5.5 or newer?